# Chunk a string into unequal lengths

Tags: ruby

I want to divide a string into chunks of unequal size (as given by `lens`).  My code works, but does not feel like idiomatic Ruby.  Any suggestions?

```
s = "red   4827spoon       jimmy john   "
lens = [6, 4, 12, 13]
i = 0
row = lens.collect {|len|
  i += len
  s[i-len, len].strip
}
```

Gives

```
["red", "4827", "spoon", "jimmy john"]
```

Comment: Using sane variable names like `lengths` and `length` ("lens" is a completely different word with a different meaning), and using `do/end` for a multi-line block, moving `i+= length` to *after* `s[i, i+len].strip` would all make the code more "idiomatic", but no, there is no magic bullet for rewriting this into a one-liner or something.

Comment: @meagar:  Wouldn't moving the `+=` after taking the substring give the wrong thing to `collect`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = "red   4827spoon       jimmy john   "
lens = [6, 4, 12, 13]
p s.unpack(lens.map{ |i| "A#{i}" }.join) #=>["red", "4827", "spoon", "jimmy john"]
p s.unpack(lens.map(&"A%d".method(:%)).join) #=> ["red", "4827", "spoon", "jimmy john"]
```

Comment: +1.  Nice awkish feel.  In your second version, what does the ampersand do?

Comment: passing `Proc` object to `map`

Answer (score 2):

This is probably less efficient because it modifies the original string a lot, but how about:

```
row = lengths.collect { |n| s.slice!(0..(n-1)).strip }
```

Answer (score 1):

I rather like Victor's unpack solutions, though they may be a bit obscure for many rubiests.  `inject` may be a bit more prosaic:

```
lens.inject([0]) {|spans,len|
  start = spans.pop
  spans << s[start,len].strip << start+len
}[0...-1]
```